# connecting slave/master jmeter with virtualbox network options

Tags: networking, jmeter, virtualbox, master-slave

Hellow
I've connected a Jmeter master in my windows PC with a jmeter slave running on an Oracle virtualbox with Untubu Xenial Xerus inside my PC, in order to make a distributed test.

When I go to the settings in my virtual box and asset the network tab as "Host-only adapter" both, master and slave connect to each other an the test goes on in the slave jmeter that is in the virtual box. The issue is that with host-only adapter the slave virtual box can´t connect to internet and the test fails. If I set the network tab as "NAT" the virtual box can conntect to internet, but jmeter master and slave can´t find each other.

So How can I set the networ option in the virtualbox in order the node slave in the virtualbox is able to connect to internet and also connect the jmeter master?

Comment: Don't really get why you need it at the SAME box. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Check section 6.3.1 [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat), I presume, that's your case:

> As the virtual machine is connected to a private network internal to
>   VirtualBox and invisible to the host, network services on the guest
>   are not accessible to the host machine or to other computers on the
>   same network. However, like a physical router, VirtualBox can make
>   selected services available to the world outside the guest through
>   port forwarding. This means that VirtualBox listens to certain ports
>   on the host and resends all packets which arrive there to the guest,
>   on the same or a different port.
>
> To an application on the host or other physical (or virtual) machines
>   on the network, it looks as though the service being proxied is
>   actually running on the host.

And don't forget to configure RMI ports at all your JMeter instances, slave or master. And use different ports for each slave.

PS Basically, it became so unnecessary complicated, that the question why do you need all that on the **same** host become even more vital.

Comment: I,ve found an easy solution. If you switch off the virtual machine and go to the menu machine > settings > network you can set two adapters. The first one as NAT adapter, in order to reach internet, and a second as "host-only adapter", and in the advandced mode > Promiscuos mode set as "allow VMs" so as the slave node is able to communicate with the host.